# Invoking Spring (4.x) Rest Service

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

Even though I´ve seen many questions about this issue, no one has been usefull to me.
I´m trying to publish a simple REST service but not matters what I do, it is not working.

My very first approach was to create a REST controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class ProductsRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService  productService;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/listproducts")
    public List<Product> products () {
        return this.productService.findAll();
    }
}
```

When invoking it (through browser) a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` was thrown

Googling I reached this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception).
The solution proposed, is to configure a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` and add it to the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. As these beans are deprecated in Spring 4.x, I used the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` this way (within my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter):

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters (final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

This conduced me to the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
```

I added the needed dependencies

```
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
```

and that result on:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Googling again I reached this other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039471/spring-getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response) But neither this one was useful.

Does anyone have any idea what the underlying problem?

Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Comment: Add the proper jackson version to your classpath, add `@EnableWebMvc` and leave the rest to Spring. You don't need to mess around with adding either `HandleAdapter` or custom `HttpMessageConverter`s.

Comment: You re right. It seems that just addind jackson deps, Spring automatically configures the handlers. Despite of this, the same error (getOutputStream() has already been called) still happens.

Comment: Do you have custom filters configured that read the request/response?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem is, there is always further googling to do.
This other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277078/spring-mvc-exception-when-using-responsebody-and-entity-with-circular-referenc) helped to solve my problem.

The thing is that the **Product** class has references to other beans that reference to Product again, so a circular reference is happening. Using DTO solved the problem.

Thanks to everyone for your support.